# Why don't these two C programs produce the same result?

Tags: c, debugging, void-pointers

I wrote this program first, it recursively calculates pi and stops when the error value is small enough.

```
 #include <stdio.h>`
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <math.h>

int threads=1;
double error=0.000001;
double func(double);


struct args{
         double l;
         double r;
         double fl; 
         double fr; 
         double area;};

double quad(struct args*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct args* res = (struct args*)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    res->l=0;
    res->r=1;
    res->fl=1;
    res->fr=0;
    res->area=0;

    double ans=quad(res);
    free(res);

    ans=ans*4;

    printf("pi=%f\n",ans);


}


double func(double x){
        x=(1-(x*x));
        x=sqrt(x);
        return x;
    }


double quad(struct args* arg){
    double m=(arg->l+arg->r)/2;
    double fm=func(m);
    double larea=(arg->fl+fm)*(m-arg->l)/2;
    double rarea = (fm+arg->fr)*(arg->r-m)/2;

    struct args* arg1 = (struct args*)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    arg1->l=arg->l;
    arg1->r=m;
    arg1->fl=arg->fl;
    arg1->fr=fm;
    arg1->area=larea;

    struct args* arg2 = (struct args*)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    arg2->l=m;
    arg2->r=arg->r;
    arg2->fl=fm;
    arg2->fr=arg->fl;
    arg2->area=rarea;
    if(fabs((larea+rarea)-arg->area)>error){
        if(threads<=1){
            larea=quad(arg1);
            rarea=quad(arg2);

            free(arg1);
            free(arg2);
        }

    }

    return(larea+rarea);
}
```

This one works as it should but then I tried to make the `quad`function return a `void pointer` instead of a `double` it looked like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>`
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <math.h>

int threads=1;
double error=0.000001;
double func(double);
struct args{
         double l;
         double r;
         double fl; 
         double fr; 
         double area;};

void* quad(struct args*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        struct args* res = (struct args*)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
        res->l=0;
        res->r=1;
        res->fl=1;
        res->fr=0;
        res->area=0;
        void* ans=quad(res);

        double val=*(double*)ans;
        val=val*4;

        free(res);


         printf("pi=%f\n",val);
   }

 double func(double x){
    x=(1-(x*x));
    x=sqrt(x);
    return x;
    }

void* quad(struct args* arg){
    double m=(arg->l+arg->r)/2;
    double fm=func(m);
    double larea=(arg->fl+fm)*(m-arg->l)/2;
    double rarea = (fm+arg->fr)*(arg->r-m)/2;

    struct args* arg1 = (struct args*)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    arg1->l=arg->l;
    arg1->r=m;
    arg1->fl=arg->fl;
    arg1->fr=fm;
    arg1->area=larea;

    struct args* arg2 = (struct args*)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    arg2->l=m;
    arg2->r=arg->r;
    arg2->fl=fm;
    arg2->fr=arg->fl;
    arg2->area=rarea;
    if(fabs((larea+rarea)-arg->area)>error){
        if(threads<=1){
            void* p1=quad(arg1);
            void* p2=quad(arg2);
            larea=*((double*)p1);
            rarea=*((double*)p2);

            free(arg1);
            free(arg2);
        }
    }


    double ret= (larea+rarea);
    void*poin=&ret;

    return poin;
}
```

This program while it compiles just gives me a completely different result, 0.042298 rather than 3.14159. I'm pretty new to C and using pointer so I'm sure I messed something up with the conversions but I can't for the life of me figure out where.

Any help figuring out why these two programs produce different results would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Neither program is valid. C langauge requires you to declare functions before calling them. You are calling an undeclared function `quad` in your code. Even in old C89/90, where function declarations were optional, behavior would be undefined. In modern C this is not even compilable. In any case, your second version attempts to return a pointer to a local variable, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to `ret`. A variable that is local to `quad()`. By the time you look at it it has been replaced.

Also dereferencing an invalid pointer is undefined behaviour. Which means your compiler is free to do whatever, like format your hard drive or start WW3.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Is it fixable? Would allocating the pointer on the heap or something work?

Comment: @JohnSlaine what was wrong with the first approach - returning a `double` value? I suggest you scrap the second version, `void*` pointers and all, and move on. Good experiment, though.

Comment: @JohnSlaine Yes, a pointer to the heap would work. Of course that would mean you have to malloc() and free().

I am assuming you are exploring the nooks and crannies of the language, because what you are doing doesn't actually make a lick of sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your non-working function returns a pointer to a local variable which will go out of scope and life when the function ends.

```
double ret = (larea+rarea);
void *poin = &ret;
return poin;
```

Whereas the working version returns the actual `double` value.

Why ever did you change the function to return a `void*` pointer anyway?

Comment: I wanted to try to make it multithreaded and I understand `pthread` wants functions that return `void*`

Comment: If that is the case you could try casting the `double` value to a `void*` pointer. So the pointer *value* is the double itself: assuming your pointers do have 64bits ;) . `return (void*)ret;` Good luck with that.

Comment: @JohnSlaine To return a value from a thread, add a member (e.g. `double result;`) to `struct args` and put the return value there.

Comment: @Weather Vane I ended up clumsily fixing it by adding a call to `malloc`

I tried your suggestion but the compiler gave "cannot convert to a pointer type".

Comment: So you end up with a memory leak if you don't `free` it?

Comment: @Weather Vane Yeah, It's not perfect by any means. Could I avoid this by doing `free`on `p1` and `p2` in the code after I `free` `arg1` and `arg2`?

Comment: I don't even know why you need to allocate memory for a *single* structure.